# input string with spaces on FOR LOOP c++

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

I already know how to input a string with space in c++, but it doesn't work in a for loop, already tried some variants of this:

```
for (int i; i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   cout << "Name: ";
   cin >> getline(cin, obj[i].name);
}
```

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

edit as requested:

this is a dummie struct to show

```
struct employee{
   string name;
}obj[10];
```

The error I get while compiling:

```
novo_teste.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
novo_teste.cpp:49:15: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::istream’ {aka ‘std::basic_istream<char>’} and ‘std::basic_istream<char>’)
   49 |           cin >> getline(cin, obj[i].nome);
      |           ~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |           |             |
      |           |             basic_istream<[...]>
      |           basic_istream<[...]>
novo_teste.cpp:49:15: note: candidate: ‘operator>>(int, int)’ <built-in>
   49 |           cin >> getline(cin, obj[i].nome);
      |           ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
novo_teste.cpp:49:15: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ to ‘int’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from novo_teste.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:120:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]’
  120 |       operator>>(__istream_type& (*__pf)(__istream_type&))
```

Comment: Can you show us enough of the rest of your code to make this a reproducible example?

Comment: `cin >> getline(cin, obj[i].name);` -> `getline(cin, obj[i].name);` The `cin` in the call to `getline` specifies the stream.

Comment: Side note: Remember to test the stream reads for success. It really sucks to have to debug to find an error that could have been trapped and handled by a simple `if (getline(...))`

Comment: Maybe `for (int i; i = 0; i < 10; i++){ cout << "Name: "; if(!getline(cin, obj[i].name)) break; }` so that the loop ends when the input ends.

Comment: Re the recent edit: Give [mre] a read-though to get a feel for the gold standard code example. It's a bit of work to make a MRE, but the real reason we want MREs is the MRE-making process is actually a powerful debugging technique. More of then than not, you get a few passes into the MRE and spot the mistake yourself. If you make the MRE early in the question writing process, odds are good you won't have to ask the question and can get back to productive work.

Comment: `for (int i; i = 0; i < 10; i++){` a for loop does not have fours parts.  You probably want `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){`

Comment: The error message clearly says that getline does not return something that you can use with `cin >>` because cin can't input to an istream.  Maybe you need something like this: https://onlinegdb.com/bt9LsIRma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever your problem is, it is **likely** not with the `getline()` function.

Try reformatting your question.

**Possible solution:**

Check if you are using cin earlier in your code, as this is what will cause the bug. You should not mix input streams. If you do use cin, add a cin.ignore() after and this will fix your issue.

If you are not using cin, debug your program, as getline() within a for loop works fine.

Comment: Makes a good comment, but a weak answer. Unfortunately because the Internet is infested with smurfholes, spammers, and the outright malicious commenting privileges are held back from new member until they've demonstrated that they're a good contributor. Usually that's about 1 or 2 good questions or answers. Until you can comment, stick to writing answers that have a concrete answer. As soon as you have to put in stuff like "Try" or "Whatever your problem is," the questions not going to have a concrete answer and shouldn't be answered.

Comment: That said, now the asker has given enough information to write a concrete answer.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for the advice, I am trying to contribute more.

Comment: It was a really stupid mistake, I wrote 'cin >> getline(cin, obj[i].name);' there for using cin in 'cin >>' and in 'getline(cin, ...)' just removed 'cin >>' and it actually worked. Thanks for the tip, won't be going to make this mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer brought me to the fix, so all credit goes to him/her. Just to update:
I was already using cin in `getline(cin, obj[i]);` so when I wrote `cin >>` gave me errors for using it twice. Rookie mistake, just removed `cin >>` and worked normally.

**Correct use:**

```
for (int i; i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   cout << "Name: ";
   getline(cin, obj[i].name);
}
```

Comment: As pointed out in the comments under the question, the for loop as written doesn't compile. `for (int i; i = 0; i < 10; i++)` has four `;` -delimited sections and can only legally have 3. It should be `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`